# Error typecasting void pointer to int

Tags: c++, xcode, cocoa, casting

I am trying to build a project on Xcode 4.2 in which there is some code which typecasts a `void*` to an `int`. This typecasting does not result in error during c++ compilation as I tried [here](http://ideone.com/Oou01q).

It was also working fine in my project until I changed the `Valid Architectures` in the `Build Settings` from `i386` to `i386 x86_64` which basically compiles the code in 64-bit mode too. I had to perform this change since I am working on de-carbonizing the project. So, after that change, many errors were introduced including this one which I am finding a bit difficult to digest. Any ideas what might be going on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On x86, a `void*` is 32 bits long, and an `int` is very likely to also be 32 bits long, so everything works.

On x86_64, however, a `void*` is 64 bits long, while an `int` is likely to remain 32 bits, so the value no longer fits.

If you need to store a pointer in an integral type, use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`, which are designed for this purpose.